# How to add xml attributes values by the recursive template using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have 100 attributes in the single node. I need the sum of all these attributes without writing the each attribute name.

```
    <Data VALUE_1="0" VALUE_2="0" VALUE_3="12" VALUE_4="33" VALUE_5="6" VALUE_6="6" VALUE_7="21"
     VALUE_8="0" VALUE_9="11" VALUE_10="0" VALUE_11="0" VALUE_12="0" VALUE_13="0" VALUE_14="0"
     VALUE_15="0" VALUE_16="0" VALUE_17="0" VALUE_18="0" VALUE_19="32" VALUE_20="0" VALUE_21="0"
      ........100 />
```

What I have tried is:--

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="rpt"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="rpt">
        <xsl:param name="inx" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="lmt" select="100"/>
        <SM0>
            <xsl:attribute name="W{$inx}"><xsl:value-of select="/Data/@Value_|$inx"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
        </SM0>
        <xsl:if test="not($inx = $lmt)">
            <xsl:call-template name="rpt">
                <xsl:with-param name="inx" select="$inx + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the xpath is not working. I have also searched for similar xpath but no luck.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I don't think so because its XSLT issue.

Comment: If you use `sum(//Data/@*)` you get the sum of all the attributes of the Data element(s).  If you want to restrict that to some certain name pattern then use e.g. `sum(//Data/@*[starts-with(local-name(), 'VALUE_')])`. I don't see why you need a recursive template. But if you expect `/Data/@Value_|$inx` to return the value of an attribute whose name is the concatenation of the string `Value_` and the variable `$inx` you are very mistaken, `|` is a union operator  and furthermore you don't build paths on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Martin that is what I am looking for.